# jquery datatable column search filter not working if i fix header

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

We are using jquery datatables.If i search  text is not appering in text filters when onkeyup and aslo in select boxes.Would you help to find solution?

My table has following code.

```
    var dTable= $("table#tableid").dataTable({
   "bStateSave":true,"bDeferRender": true,"sPaginationType":"full_numbers","iDisplayLength":25,
        "fnStateSaveParams": function (oSettings, oData)
            {       

                if($('#enquerydata_range_from_5').val()){               
                    oData.from = $('#enquerydata_range_from_5').val();
                }else{
                    oData.from = '';
                }
                if($('#enquerydata_range_to_5').val()){             
                    oData.to = $('#enquerydata_range_to_5').val();
                }else{
                    oData.to = '';
                }           
            },
            "fnStateLoadParams": function (oSettings, oData)
            {               
                setTimeout(function(){ if(oData.from || oData.to){$('#enquerydata_range_from_5').val(oData.from); $('#enquerydata_range_to_5').val(oData.to); dTable.fnDraw(); }},500);     

            },




}).columnFilter({sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
                aoColumns: [ 
                            null,
                            { type: "c-name" },
                            { type: "contact" },    
                            { type: "project-name" },                               
                            null,                       
                            { type: "date-range" },
                            { type: "ptype-select" },
                            { type: "ptype-select" },
                            null,
                            { type: "ptype-select" },                               
                ]
}); 

new FixedHeader(dTable,{"alwaysCloneTop": true,"bStateSaveParams":false});
```